# How can I find out how many files ending in .c or .cpp inside a directory contain the string: string?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, files

How can I find out how many files ending in .c or .cpp inside a directory contain the string: string?

The string can occur anywhere in the entire file, including comments or as part of a larger string.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that your filenames cannot contain newlines, then

```
grep -rFl --include='*.c' --include='*.cpp' string . | wc -l
```

Otherwise

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec grep -Fq string {} \; -printf x | wc -c
```

Comment: Completely forgot `grep` has `--include` flag. +1 for that

Answer (score 2):

Use the grep command to find out:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.cpp"  \) -exec grep "string" {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -l string *.c *.cpp | wc -l
```

- If any filenames contain newlines, the count will be too high.
- If the globs fail to match, you will get an error like `grep: *.c: No such file or directory`, but the count will still be correct.

This is like a quick and dirty version of [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1108982/301745).

Comment: Consider also `shopt -s dotglob` or  adding `.*.c  .*.cpp` to account for filenames with leading dot.  Also consider `2>/dev/null` if you don't wanna see the error message.

Comment: @Serg All good points. `grep -s` will also hide error messages, like `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way would be via `bash` [recursive glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob) combined with [single match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14093511/3701431) parameter in `grep` (one file - one match) :

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -m 1 'string' */**.{c,cpp}  | wc -l
```

Why not `grep -R` ? Because  `-R` walks through all files, and doesn't filter `.c` or `.cpp` files, so we use bash's globbing to do that job.

Otherwise, for shell-agnostic way you can use `find`:

```
find -type f \( -iname "*.c" -or -iname "*.cpp" \) -exec grep -q 'string' {} \; -and -print | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the tool [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) ([snap](https://snapcraft.io/rg)) for these kinds of task (grepping in source code repositories):

```
$ rg -g '*.c' -g '*.cpp' -l string | wc -l
```

The following command may also be useful:

```
$ rg -t c -t cpp -l string | wc -l
```

Which searches files with the following extensions:

```
$ rg --type-list | grep -E '^c:|^cpp:'
c: *.H, *.c, *.h
cpp: *.C, *.H, *.cc, *.cpp, *.cxx, *.h, *.hh, *.hpp, *.hxx, *.inl
```

The flags used are:

```
    -l, --files-with-matches                
        Only print the paths with at least one match.

        This overrides --files-without-match.

    -g, --glob <GLOB>...                    
        Include or exclude files and directories for searching that match the given
        glob. This always overrides any other ignore logic. Multiple glob flags may be
        used. Globbing rules match .gitignore globs. Precede a glob with a ! to exclude
        it.

    -t, --type <TYPE>...                    
        Only search files matching TYPE. Multiple type flags may be provided. Use the
        --type-list flag to list all available types.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out how many files end in `.c` or `.cpp` that contains the word "string" by executing:

`cat *.c* | grep -i "string" | wc -l`